# Collection<T> is not a valid return type error using Change Method Signature Refactor on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, eclipse-neon

I've moved to Eclipse Neon recently and when I try to use the Change Method Signature(Ctrl+Shift+C) Refactor operation an error shows up: "Collection is not a valid return type". It doesn't happen to methods which return Object or primitive types, just for collections. I remeber I've done this before on former Eclipse versions.

Comment: Please show your code, I can not reproduce the problem.

Comment: Perhaps report this as a bug at bugs.eclipse.org -- or look there at least to see if it was solved already.

Comment: It just happens to any method that return a Collection<T>. I've tried to find a solution on eclipse foruns but I couldn't find it. I will report the bug.